# 快把大衣穿穿！When is it wrong?

Tags: grammar

In our book under 改錯句 there is the following exercise:
[image]

> 外邊很冷，快把大衣穿穿！

I assume they consider it wrong because the object is not definite. Is that so, or is there any other reason?

If the context makes it clear that we are talking about a specific 大衣，would the sentence be ok, or do I absolutely need to grammatically express the definite nature by

> 那件大衣/你的大衣/爸爸送給你的大衣⋯?

Edit:

according to our book, reduplication of the verb makes the predicate complex, fulfilling the requirement for 把字句。 The example given is: 把桌子擦擦。

Comment: >> 外邊很冷，快把大衣「穿上」！

Comment: @user3a according to our book, reduplication of the verb makes the predicate complex, fulfilling the requirement for 把字句。

Comment: in support of comment #1: the meaning of reduplication depends on the verb in question, 穿穿 is often used in the sense of trying something on, 擦擦 indicates wiping back and forth

Comment: @user6065 I don’t see what makes 擦擦 have the meaning of a change as opposed to 穿穿，but I get why the meaning of 試試 might not fit the change required for 把。

Comment: "back and forth" seems to be wrong, instead it should have said "briefly" or "a little bit", also regarding 把, definiteness should not be taken too literally (discussed before)

Comment: re comments #3.5 (back and forth), there is the suggestion that verb reduplication may be associated with short-period periodic activity, e.g. 点点／摇摇头、挥挥手、眨眨眼、喘喘气，闪闪（e.g.星光闪闪),烁烁（e.g.“烁烁三星列，拳拳月初生。”吹吹:到外面去吹吹风（呼吸新鲜空气）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ludi wrote:

> *according to our book, reduplication of the verb makes the predicate complex, fulfilling the requirement for (**把**)字句*

Reduplication of verb imply the verb is in 'a slight degree', 'a casual manner' or 'tentative manner'

Examples:

吃 = eat

吃吃 =  (slightly/ casually) eat

试 = try

试试 = (slightly/ tentatively) try

The first part of the sentence '外邊很冷' is a reason; the second part of the sentence '快把大衣穿穿 is a request/ command, you can switch the positions of the 'request/ command' and the 'reason' and the meaning would be the same. '快把大衣穿穿, (because) 外邊很冷'

Since this sentence request/ command  the object to do something definite, it shouldn't be in reduplication form that implies it is in 'slight', 'casual' or 'tentatively' manner

user3a is correct:

> 外邊很冷，快把大衣「穿上」

*把 is not an important factor in choosing reduplicate the verb or not.
You shouldn't  reduplicate 穿 in "外邊很冷，快穿上大衣" neither.*

Comment: very helpful！ But why is 把桌子擦擦 different? Because it’s not part of a command?

Comment: @Ludi 把桌子擦拭 means "wipe the table"; 把桌子擦擦 means "wipe the table (slightly)" If you drop  the 把 , the difference would become more clear; 擦桌子 = 'wipe the table' ; 擦擦桌子 = '(slightly) wipe the table  '

Comment: is theimportant difference is that you can slightly 擦， but not slightly 穿，so we know 穿穿 means 試試穿，which doesn’t fit the requirements of change for 把？

Comment: Yes, 把 is a depositive marker that marks the object to be deposited of,  '穿穿' (tentatively wear)  doesn't fulfill the  'depositive' function of the verb.

Comment: But 擦擦 (slightly wipe) is still a fulfillment of the the 'depositive' function of 把 (you are wiping the table in a slight degree, but you still clean it)  ;  '穿穿' (tentatively wear) implies you may take it off if you don't like it, that doesn't deposit the object (大衣)

Comment: That's that kind of question only learn-Mandarin-as-from-textbook speakers can understand. Or people who really take a good look at the Mandarin language.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally acceptable to say that to a toddler.