# Single-worded verbs being repeated when use in a sentence

Tags: grammar, mandarin

So in Mandarin there are verbs like 数 means count and 试 means try but I usually them being doubled when use in a sentence (I.e: 请数数 = Please count). Can somebody explains for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called verb reduplication and it is not the first time I explain it.

From my answer to another question [What is the purpose of verb reduplication?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31120/what-is-the-purpose-of-verb-reduplication)

> Phrases like 笑笑，看看，走走 or 吃吃 are verb reduplication, it serves to indicate the verb is in a slight degree or a casual manner

From my answer to yet another question [快把大衣穿穿！When is it wrong?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30419/%e5%bf%ab%e6%8a%8a%e5%a4%a7%e8%a1%a3%e7%a9%bf%e7%a9%bf-when-is-it-wrong)

> Reduplication of verb imply the verb is in 'a slight degree', 'a casual manner' or 'tentative manner'
>
> Examples:
>
> 吃 = eat
>
> 吃吃 = (slightly/ casually) eat
>
> 试 = try
>
> 试试 = (slightly/ tentatively) try

The difference between 请数 and 请数数 is 请数 sounds like a blunt demand; 请数数 sounds less demanding (reduplicate the verb 数 hinting you make the statement in a tentative manner. Not that you are not sure the other person should count, just you are not forcefully telling him to do so)